# Android Studio force shutdown my computer

Tags: android-studio

I tried to import existing or creating new project in AS. When it builds gradle and indexing suddenly all freezes and automatically force shutdown the computer. I tried the update version of oracle Java8, Java7. removed other programs, not even chrome too only default windows process. But nothing worked.
I'm running core i7(2600) nvidia gt430 8gb-DDR3 RAM. I already did complete new installation windows 7 so many times. Even i removed .gradle .config files from everywhere and in android studio running in offline gradle mode. But nothing happened. I need help please. It still force shutdown my pc without any error after 15 or 20 sec running android studio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was my Java JDK version. Google fixed the JDK 7.67 but i installed the update of JAVA 8. Now i'm using JAVA 7 and the problem is fixed.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hYg4y.png)
download JAVA 7 from here
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html